Monitoring the Evolution of Inequality in Time-Dependent Distributions
I created a self-contained example in R that you find at the end of the post. I would like to be reassured that what I do makes sense. I have a dataset with 2 variables: year is a time variable, pc_gdp is a numerical value. In other words, I have a distribution of pc_gdp values which evolves in time.
I would like investigate the evolution of the inequality of the distribution in time.
To do so, I calculate 3 indicators

The Gini coefficient by year
The Herfindahl–Hirschman Index by year
The ratio of the standard deviation to the mean by year

Based on the results which I plot below, in the last couple of years in the data I see a clear downfall of the inequality of the distribution regardless of the indicator, so this is a robust conclusion.
My question is if anyone sees any methodological mistakes in what I did.
In particular, I do not believe that simply monitoring the evolution of the standard deviation  of the distribution is sound, seen that the mean of the distribution also evolves in time.
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor


##functions to calculate two inequality indicators

hhi_index <- function(x){

    y <- x/sum(x)

    res <- sum(y^2)
    return(res)
    
}


Gini <- function (x, corr = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) 
{
if (!na.rm && any(is.na(x))) 
    return(NA_real_)
x <- as.numeric(na.omit(x))
n <- length(x)
x <- sort(x)
G <- sum(x * 1L:n)
G <- 2 * G/sum(x) - (n + 1L)
if (corr) 
    G/(n - 1L)
else G/n
}


df_gdp <- structure(list(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022
), pc_gdp = c(0.656703279305, 0.54631699031, 0.58196184703, 0.575068135673, 
0.4468146134, 0.553818412283, 0.554339539542, 0.527367003856, 
0.493997220658, 0.505873819467, 1.996547177672, 2.465318678067, 
1.4574790262461, 0.775696219076, 0.60147553071, 0.539584411203, 
0.552592515744, 0.569609459622, 0.522068293311, 0.612308622651, 
0.536268278622, 0.817999589627, 0.961189202902, 1.4340967955946, 
1.2975770617889, 1.027445402858, 0.096535369754, 0.8441743256, 
0.91128719989, 1.20820003542, 2.4644159172, 1.5136927872, 1.378508065, 
1.4705049796, 1.13674119857, 0.68273644487, 1.43840432026, 1.685094095428, 
1.011494765431, 0.651730771201, 0.75662814085, 0.65628204947, 
0.84487222288, 0.76597714358, 0.76151396995, 0.67373684116, 0.57317241275, 
0.48332027618, 0.53930387818, 1.5087153837, 2.13321004103, 0.53773776932, 
0.782117387134, 0.910564135402, 1.0169214559, 1.134023655237, 
1.161086397211, 1.3069013139752, 1.4385781983389, 1.509052631214, 
1.748296189183, 1.515461202231, 2.7425715605341, 3.625801656221, 
1.4346706388101, 0.6739769937443, 0.5527611405251, 0.4737931717436, 
0.4846664372712, 1.120507032308, 1.2602530027903, 1.3791203208961, 
1.3911593055129, 1.3808878538096, 1.5118527908445, 3.712392974519, 
3.17975187108007, 1.90026919466859, 0.85883955038, 0.90845855824, 
0.96894456082, 0.958386325878, 0.93906694935, 1.23023911546, 
1.6013209588181, 1.5245731224, 1.496134037741, 1.434770053039, 
2.480026237968, 1.5675922594259, 1.39317477133, 0.29577513346, 
0.37680239624, 0.41375419039, 0.74869841322, 1.008625, 0.98892718092, 
0.83882027677, 1.03859621886, 1.07610925952, 1.23195107246, 1.693845982377, 
1.410704487283, 0.920405279466, 0.602248775009, 0.64850039544, 
0.447949465606, 0.781328014518, 0.539770090454, 0.552678287242, 
0.51637134675, 0.328342005542, 0.339176446697, 0.570876976534, 
4.319445883345, 3.056887818701, 1.377815683707, 0.4564692183888, 
0.4220820640184, 0.3787651024954, 0.30824640147, 0.3390442588854, 
0.280587942911, 0.2801713961746, 0.334704332277, 0.4204859739704, 
0.474842527316, 0.8898013819934, 1.1131866115691, 1.2718635379389, 
1.103886816845, 1.245454040951, 1.160007960424, 1.229434169792, 
1.2438284247, 1.08549526881, 0.92569930894, 0.967138308493, 0.98217387723, 
0.92232429714, 1.5241215963, 1.596350939044, 0.94480696056, 0.78911673413174, 
0.6592143426148, 0.7422383159888, 0.6508534384028, 0.7276032696238, 
0.7660439876055, 0.7405864348668, 1.002495963142, 0.9459611696121, 
0.975598679315, 2.2743019520077, 2.67660625142824, 1.69731199829, 
0.5839329669, 0.7133201569, 0.8537752359, 1.169535296, 1.4540223404, 
1.540324366, 1.33203066269, 2.670423632864, 2.199108762676, 0.83962578241, 
2.049429658384, 1.173199731911, 1.194058498847, 1.467955061243, 
1.703712066254, 1.3458917571617, 2.24070480049, 2.6893575050093, 
2.1637113039147, 1.787843870362, 3.1260049694, 3.6171413494205, 
2.0852533473, 0.96365991177, 0.606585565092, 0.49038756184, 0.64126268661, 
0.47488603707, 0.32844587939, 0.26649392091, 0.285578960016, 
0.273643828034, 0.340241780931, 0.4072368118425, 0.7061115894759, 
0.312661602157, 0.2413995820286, 0.2239964828295, 0.2615185666467, 
0.2184158235008, 0.2283815290039, 0.2257209924013, 0.2300793404311, 
0.3479489302725, 0.44691452684705, 0.45058980962587, 2.02657077978332, 
2.1110440575718, 1.4182906064327, 0.5794998041, 0.6752060459, 
0.67119352585, 0.58660039101, 0.49450797814, 0.85000536301, 0.86668894744, 
1.04100472776, 1.319793622, 1.55874754882, 2.00164308888, 1.587315924031, 
1.1339461421, 0.22750259441, 0.23989842113, 0.21024515991, 0.33086354238, 
0.36252316501, 0.3888817003, 0.344295376, 0.2710893468, 0.2736539098, 
0.3104743569, 1.10465658885, 0.81299503, 0.6655503223, 0.99118155638, 
1.35075173881, 4.5663493633, 2.5396815517, 3.05387288027, 3.40188618238, 
2.4044488146, 3.6340592592, 1.0925958891, 1.069115038945, 2.703903656252, 
2.815801201622, 1.006825707288, 1.250948527, 1.40024638, 1.414054052, 
1.876835444, 0.9396931819, 1.309296, 1.187638092, 1.1825176441, 
2.2691007721, 1.69678321412, 4.2275402967, 3.9885705869, 1.50650639489, 
0.425129632755, 0.417708796131, 0.379453363701, 0.348976669435, 
0.352668133941, 0.350735391141, 0.407484751183, 0.3932400787, 
0.420580456152, 0.409780960224, 0.8751632186104, 1.500102447492, 
1.0352371684916, 1.001536451941, 0.7854611410237, 0.780887108125, 
0.7691662507035, 1.2929786027563, 0.8789069550643, 1.1149212536245, 
1.5416601962838, 1.2149491143646, 1.11703728347499, 5.16658033852155, 
1.8132424726301, 0.9271198700437, 1.27267739558, 1.010873595029, 
0.692281398167, 0.49082815103, 0.43530502401, 0.519138564913, 
0.398091369383, 0.550558551707, 0.581465888808, 0.529855411322, 
1.63675994983, 1.42781712785, 0.950680772795, 0.22403531512, 
0.46420107152, 0.594453936919, 0.63357239413, 0.775431032011, 
0.806185723964, 0.64378241962, 0.51786755104, 0.551281729653, 
0.65497691047, 1.237669000228, 1.581373473567, 1.465188209782, 
1.34267774648, 1.31274430016, 0.7527085215, 0.76413675414, 0.75131632967, 
0.693792967598, 0.781684040112, 0.919515524352, 0.9131322935051, 
0.826466283174, 1.02796299817, 1.041863271964, 0.893673630696, 
1.000530767893, 1.20343396218, 1.24272727184, 1.3322246578, 1.23758244262, 
1.1263272443, 0.82148514551, 0.886683018238, 0.9426755952, 0.85821193378, 
3.543861272038, 3.007296940552, 0.847357893849, 0.44022994362, 
0.23753481939, 0.1798505399, 0.2716912749, 0.414899213, 0.57503370482, 
0.47502336845, 0.32340377671, 0.515016687, 0.6488559275, 1.77030406826, 
2.22186889174, 0.88510036163)), row.names = c(NA, -348L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

    
df_gdp |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 348
#> Columns: 2
#> $ year   <dbl> 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 202…
#> $ pc_gdp <dbl> 0.6567033, 0.5463170, 0.5819618, 0.5750681, 0.4468146, 0.553818…


##In this dataset, year is a time variable. I have an evolving distribution
## of values pc_gdp for every year

## I want to monitor the evolution of the inequality of the distribution,
## and I use three indicators

## Gini coefficient, calculated for every year
## Herfindahl–Hirschman Index again for every year
## ratio of the standard deviation to the mean for every year

df_ineq <- df_gdp |>
    group_by(year) |>
    summarise(hhi=hhi_index(pc_gdp),
              ## hhi_norm=hhi_index_norm(pc_gdp),
              gini=Gini(pc_gdp),
              ratio=sd(pc_gdp)/mean(pc_gdp)) |>
    ungroup()


df_ineq |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 13
#> Columns: 4
#> $ year  <dbl> 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020…
#> $ hhi   <dbl> 0.05059875, 0.04693088, 0.07483711, 0.05136797, 0.05521649, 0.05…
#> $ gini  <dbl> 0.3069547, 0.2670634, 0.3763781, 0.3181310, 0.3456610, 0.3165364…
#> $ ratio <dbl> 0.5728788, 0.4785509, 0.9917638, 0.6338906, 0.7139494, 0.6825659…


## I prepare the data for plotting

df_ineq_long <- df_ineq |>
    pivot_longer(cols=hhi:ratio, names_to="indicator")



diff_names <- c(
    `hhi` = "Herfindahl–Hirschman Index",
      `gini` = "Gini Index",
                    `ratio` = "Standard deviation over mean"
                    )
gpl <- ggplot(df_ineq_long, aes(x=year, y=value
                       )) +

theme_bw()+
    
geom_point(size=3) +
geom_line(linewidth=1)+

    scale_x_continuous(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2), breaks=pretty_breaks(5))+
    facet_wrap( ~indicator  , nrow = 1, scales = "free_y",
               labeller=as_labeller(diff_names))+
    
xlab("Year")+
 ylab(NULL)


gpl


sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#> Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.11.0 
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.11.0
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> time zone: Europe/Brussels
#> tzcode source: system (glibc)
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] scales_1.3.0    lubridate_1.9.3 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.1  
#>  [5] dplyr_1.1.4     purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.5     tidyr_1.3.1    
#>  [9] tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.5.1   tidyverse_2.0.0
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] gtable_0.3.5      compiler_4.4.0    reprex_2.1.0      tidyselect_1.2.1 
#>  [5] yaml_2.3.8        fastmap_1.1.1     R6_2.5.1          labeling_0.4.3   
#>  [9] generics_0.1.3    knitr_1.46        munsell_0.5.1     R.cache_0.16.0   
#> [13] tzdb_0.4.0        pillar_1.9.0      R.utils_2.12.3    rlang_1.1.3      
#> [17] utf8_1.2.4        stringi_1.8.4     xfun_0.43         fs_1.6.4         
#> [21] timechange_0.3.0  cli_3.6.2         withr_3.0.0       magrittr_2.0.3   
#> [25] digest_0.6.35     grid_4.4.0        hms_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.4  
#> [29] R.methodsS3_1.8.2 R.oo_1.26.0       vctrs_0.6.5       evaluate_0.23    
#> [33] glue_1.7.0        farver_2.1.1      styler_1.10.3     fansi_1.0.6      
#> [37] colorspace_2.1-0  rmarkdown_2.26    tools_4.4.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3  
#> [41] htmltools_0.5.8.1

Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0
